# Importing cucumber libraries in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, import, intellij-plugin, cucumber-java

So I'm trying to switch over from Eclipse to IntelliJ, but I'm having a little trouble with imports. The error is in the 5th and 6th line, for some reason io isn't being imported. I've already downloaded the necessary libraries and added them (check the 2nd picture). What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems you need "cucumber-junit" dependency as well.

Comment: It looks like you aren't using a dependency management tool. Have a look at Maven or Gradle. Then you only have to track the version of Cucumber are using. The tutorials use it too https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: @mpkorstanje sweet, thanks for introducing me to Gradle!